# Multiple conditions in where clause, is there any way to simply it in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm just checking whether any student has got 35 marks in any subject. Is there any way to simplify it like this where (phy,che,math,cs,eng) in (35)?

```
with temp_table as(
select "studentA" name,36 as phy, 67 as che,75 math,65 cs,64 eng union all
select "studentB" name,44, 57, 37, 73, 57 union all
select "studentC" name,94, 87, 48, 72, 63
)
select * from temp_table where phy=35 or che=35 or math=35 or cs=35 or eng=35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with temp_table as(
select "studentA" name,36 as phy, 67 as che,75 math,65 cs,64 eng union all
select "studentB" name,44, 57, 37, 73, 57 union all
select "studentC" name,94, 87, 48, 72, 63
)
select * from temp_table where 35 IN (phy, che, math, cs, eng)
```

(Be aware that if any of the columns is `NULL`, however, the `IN` comparison will return `NULL`)